# mail sending in java( I am using java mail api for this)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I have written code for mail sending in java( I am using java mail api for this). Here uerId and Password(For authentication purpose) I am giving of my domain because I want my email server to be use.

The Problem is, when I am sending mail from localhost it is working fine, But when I am deploying on my live staging server,and trying to send the mail, it is giving following exception:

```
Apr 08, 2015 7:32:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.dreamdays.ae, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.dreamdays.ae, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.dreamdays.ae, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:227)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1672)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
    at com.service.MailMail.sendMail(MailMail.java:34)
    at com.controller.UserController.saveUser(UserController.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:603)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:792)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Code is below, Please check it and help me out.

```
public class MailDao {
 private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "mail.dreamdays.ae";

    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER ="cpverma@dreamdays.ae"; 
     private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "********";  


 public void postMail(String emailTo, String recipients[ ], String subject, String message , String from) throws MessagingException, AuthenticationFailedException 
     {
         boolean debug = false; 
         //Set the host smtp address 
     Properties props = new Properties(); 
         props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME); 
         props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 


 try{

     Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
     Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
    // session.setDebug(debug); 
     // create a message 
     Message msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
     // set the from and to address 
     InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from); 
     msg.setFrom(addressFrom); 
//   InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length]; 

     InternetAddress[] emailToArr = new InternetAddress[1];
     emailToArr[0] =  new InternetAddress(emailTo);
     System.out.println("emailTo---"+emailTo);
     msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, emailToArr); 

    // if(recipients.length >0)
    //  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, emailToArr);

     // Setting the Subject and Content Type 
     msg.setSubject(subject); 
     msg.setContent(message, "text/html"); 
     Transport.send(msg); 


         System.out.println("emailTo3---"+emailTo);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("mail sending failed:--"+e);
    }

        } 
     private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
         public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
             String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER; 
             String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD; 
             return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
             } 
         }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: The exception is pretty clear, what don't you understand in "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.dreamdays.ae, port: 25;"

Comment: Seems like your server cannot find the mailserver. Check the network, DNS and firewall settings for your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception means that connection to the host is timing out which might be because of the host not being available. So verify whether the connection to the host is possible by using telnet

```
telnet mail.dreamdays.ae 25
```

Also you are able to connect using telnet then there should not be any problem in sending mail.

So ensure that the host server is up and available in the first place

Comment: Hey, Thanks Aarish for your answer when I am verifying the connection using    telnet mail.dreamdays.ae 25    .It is showing                       Trying 216.154.217.84...
Connected to mail.dreamdays.ae.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 dreamdays.ae ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.1/8.13.1; Wed, 8 Apr 2015 04:55:52 -0400    This means it connecting to mail server mail.dreamdays.ae ? if connecting then what could be the other the problem due to which mail is not going on live server?

Comment: @ChandraPrakashVerma: Ya it is connecting to the server.So there should not any problem in connecting and sending mail to it too. Please check again